# Blender Fluid Simulation Not Working

Tags: fluid-simulation

I have been meaning to ask this question for a while
I used to do fluid simulations a lot and when they changed to flip they just don't work anymore.

In the viewport the only thing that is showing is these particles [image: Image of viewport]

I watched some tutorials and I set it up how they said to and the collision objects also aren't working. Even in renders the fluid doesn't show up.
Here is a link to a google drive with the .blend file so someone can tell me what I did wrong [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/19_g4J5gfPrPKjMvvnoVI1fWSbn10sQXb?usp=sharing)
Thanks

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of the question specific to what you are asking and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you tick the Mesh checkbox in the physics panel of your liquid simulation and then click on bake mesh
[image]
[image]